# What is the Unique ID for the Library for Plaid in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, plaid

I am getting back errors that Plaid is not defined in Apps Script while integrating Plaid into Google Sheets. ChatGPT told me to add the Plaid library using the unique ID found in the docs, but I’ve looked everywhere and can’t find it. Does anyone know where I could find this?

I tried running the code and expected it to work but got back an error… my guess is that I need to install the Plaid library but I’m not sure.